# In a Docker app, access to /proc/self/pagemap shows Operation not permitted

Tags: linux, docker

As said in the title, in OS, for /proc//pagemap in OS, owner is the user starting this app, permission is -r--------. And user in Docker app is another user, who cannot read this file. So what can we do to read it inside Docker app?

Comment: With --priviledged, it can work as expected, but from man, docker will enable access to all the devices on the host...not such great solution.

Comment: Access here just means read permission instead of write permission. /proc file system is mounted read only.

Answer (score 0):

if i understand your question right : You may need to use setuid() to become the effective user to read the file. if you have a java app then wrap it in shell script and call from java.

So this below is what you can do, as an example

1. write a shell script or c program : say "proc_read_util" to read and print /proc/self/pagemap file
2. chmod u+s proc_read_util
3. call this program from you app, get the output and process.

Comment: Inside docker app, both ruid and euid is root. Very strange, for /proc/vmallocinfo with same permission of -r--------, it can be read, but not for /proc/self/pagemap.

Answer (score 0):

Linux since version 4.0, including those version backported by the patch (https://lwn.net/Articles/642075/), needs CAP_SYS_ADMIN to access /proc/pid/pagemap. Currently, run docker with --priviledged can help with situation with the cost of lost meaning using Docker.